# How to create indeed.com like search?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, search-engine, reverse

If you have used indeed.com before, you may know that for the keywords you look for, it returns a traditional search results as long as multiple search refinement options on the left side of screen.

For example, searching for keyword "designer", the refinement options are:

```
Salary Estimate
    $40,000+ (45982)
    $60,000+ (29795)
    $80,000+ (15966)
    $100,000+ (6896)
    $120,000+ (2828)
Title
    Floral Design Specialist (945)
    Hair Stylist (817)
    GRAPHIC DESIGNER (630)
    Hourly Associates/Co-managers (589)
    Web designer (584)
    more »
Company
    Kelly Services (1862)
    Unlisted Company (1133)
    CyberCoders Engineering (1058)
    Michaels Arts & Crafts (947)
    ULTA (818)
    Elance (767)
Location
    New York, NY (2960)
    San Francisco, CA (1633)
    Chicago, IL (1184)
    Houston, TX (1057)
    Seattle, WA (1025)
    more »
Job Type
    Full-time (45687)
    Part-time (2196)
    Contract (8204)
    Internship (720)
    Temporary (1093)
```

How does it gather statistics information so quickly (e.g. the number of job offers in each salary range). Looks like the refinement options are created in realtime since minor keywords load fast too.

Is there a specific SQL technique to create such feature? Or is there a manual on the web explaining the tech behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technology used in Indeed.com and other search engines is known as [inverted indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) which is at the core of how search engines work (e.g Google). The filtering you refer to ("refinement options") are known as facets.

You can use [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), a full-fledged search server built using Lucene and easily integrable into your application using its RESTful API. Comes out-of-the-box with several features such as faceting, caching, scaling, spell-checking, etc. Is also used by several sites such as Netflix, C-Net, AOL etc. - hence stable, scalable and battle-tested.

If you want to dig deep into facet based filtering works, lookup Bitsets/Bitarrays and is described in this [article](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/04/lucene-search-within-search-with.html).

Comment: Previous answers about using an inverted index and a denormalized doc store are good. Our next tech talk (http://engineering.indeed.com/talks/machine-learning-at-indeed-scaling-decision-trees/) will be talking a bit more about the power of inverted indexes in the context of building decision trees for machine learning. We use this ML approach for result ranking. I'll follow up here with links to slides and video after the talk.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that they load "too fast"? They certainly have nice, scaled architecture, they use caching for sure, they might be using some denormalized datastore to accelerate some computations and queries.

Take a look at google and number of web pages worldwide - you also think that google works too fast?

Comment: Nowhere in the question does the original author say that the site is too fast. He mentions that it is fast and asks how to do something similar.

Comment: -1 to even this out to 0 since you've completely fabricated the fact he said "too fast" and that's what your entire answer refers to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mios said and as Daimon mentioned it does use a denormalized doc store. Here is a link to Indeed's tech talk about its docstore

http://engineering.indeed.com/blog/2013/03/indeedeng-from-1-to-1-billion-video/

Also another related article on their Engineering blog:
http://engineering.indeed.com/blog/2013/10/serving-over-1-billion-documents-per-day-with-docstore-v2/